# How to get the list of programs and service program have binded a given RPGLE module for a specific library

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Suppose i have a Rpgle modle name and a library name. How do i find out for that library list what is the list of programs and service programs that module is binded to.

Comment: the `QBNLPGMI` and `QBNLSPGM` APIs provide this information.  https://www.itjungle.com/2012/08/22/fhg082212-story02/

Answer (score 5):

if you are on 7.3 or higher you can use sql. You can find further information [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzajq/rzajqviewboundmodule.htm).

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM qsys2.bound_module_info
 WHERE bound_module = 'YOUR_MODULE' AND
       bound_module_library = 'YOUR_LIBRARY';
```

Comment: might add `and program_library = 'SOMELIB'` otherwise it's going to look at ILE program in every library on the system.

Comment: I only have the module name.

Comment: take a took at the `qsys.bound_module_info` view instead then